# to write a SQL query which select rows where column value changed from previous row

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE status( id serial NOT NULL,
id integer,
plan smallint,
ime timestamp without time zone
CONSTRAINT data_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id))
WITH (OIDS=FALSE);
ALTER TABLE data
OWNER TO postgres;
```

Index: data_idx

```
CREATE INDEX data_idx
ON data
USING btree
(time, id);
```

I have a table like this

```
id    val         plan     time
 1    8300        1      2011-01-01        
 2    8300        1      2011-01-02         
 3    8300        2      2011-01-03         
 4    9600        1      2011-01-04         
 5    9600        2      2011-01-05
```

How do I select the rows where sigplan changed from the previous row for that siteId?

In the example above, the query should return the rows

```
2011-01-03 (sigplan changed from 1 to 2 between 2011-01-01 and 2011-01-03 for 8300), 
2011-01-05(sigplan changed from 1 to 2 between 2011-01-04 and 2011-01-05 for 9600).
```

- The table contains lot of data so the query should be optimized.

Comment: So, you are only interested in records like:

`id_this - id_previous = 1 AND siteId_this = siteId_previous AND sigplan_this <> sigplan_previous`

Correct?

Comment: yes. for each siteId if sigplan changes, i need to reurn that row.

Comment: @sangeethanair  will it cahange from 2 to 3 or more?

Comment: MySQL and PostgreSQL are two different products. In which do you need this?

Comment: it Changes from 2 to 3 and more. im using postgres sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT siteId, sigplan, MAX(server_time) FROM traffview.status_data 
GROUP BY siteId, sigplan   
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1 AND MAX(server_time) > 'XXXXX' AND MAX(server_time) < 'XXXXX'
```

Comment: I want to also lnclude a where clause in which a server_time limit like                  where server_time>XXXX and  server_time,XXXX     how to do this?

Comment: @sangeethanair Updated the answer

Comment: taking too long to execute.

Comment: Please refer https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-optimization.html to optimize group by

Answer (score 1):

This version doesn't have a sub-query, but does assume that you have consecutive IDs.

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM traffview AS t1, traffview AS t2 
WHERE 
    t1.siteId = t2.siteId 
    AND t1.sigplan <> t2.sigplan
    AND t1.id - t2.id = 1
ORDER BY 
    t1.server_time
```

Comment: Sorry Im not aware much about this. But it is not executing in postgres. shows some syntax error.

Comment: Sorry... I had my brain wired for `C#`. I have changed the incorrect `!=` inequality operator to the correct `<>`one.

Comment: Updated. The query was originally written to be conceptual. I have changed it.

Answer (score 0):

The annoying part is figuring out which is the previous row id with the same siteId. After that it is pretty easy by joining the table with itself.

```
SELECT t1.* FROM table t1, table t2 
WHERE t1.sigplan != t2.sigplan 
AND t2.id = (SELECT MAX(t3.id) FROM table t3 WHERE t3.id < t1.id)
```

If the table is moderately (not extremely) large I would consider doing this in application code instead, or by storing the change flag in its own column when writing a new row. A subquery for each row in the table has very poor performance.

Comment: Or just write a better query ;-)

Comment: Be my guest. My aim was mainly to outline the different possibilities of solving this or similar problems, as the complete picture isn't apparent from the question.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know postgres

Comment: @Strawberry If you know SQL, then the differences between PostgreSQL, MySQL, Oracle, SQLServer, Sybase, ... are largely limited to syntax and some data-types. The logic stays the same :)

Comment: Syntax then. I'll go with syntax.

Answer (score 0):

In case you compare with previous rows it is useful to use `LAG` function which does the job for you:

```
SELECT sub.*
FROM (
  SELECT 
    plan AS curr_plan,
    LAG(plan) OVER (PARTITION BY val ORDER BY time) AS prev_plan,
    val,
    time
) sub
WHERE
  sub.prev_plan IS NOT NULL AND sub.prev_plan <> sub.curr_plan;
```